# Distribute periodic messages on cycles

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, load-balancing

I'm currently facing a problem:
I have messages that have to be sent periodically. There are multiple (different) intervals which each have multiple messages. There is a limit how many messages can be put into one cycle. That means I have to offset the interval start by a few cycles to distribute the messages to avoid exceeding the cycle limit.

Simple example:

Constrain: Max 3 messages per cycle

- Interval A = 2

  - messages [0, 1]
- Interval B = 3

  - messages [2, 3, 4, 5]

No offsets

| cycle | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| messages | 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 | - | 0, 1 | 2, 3, 4, 5 | 0, 1 | - | 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 | - | 0, 1 | 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 |

| cycle | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| messages | 0, 1 | - | 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 | - | 0, 1 | 2, 3, 4, 5 | 0, 1 | - | 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 | - |

With offsets

- Offsets A [0, 1]
- Offsets B [1, 2, 0, 0]

| cycle | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| messages | 0, 4, 5 | 1, 2 | 0, 3 | 1, 4, 5 | 0, 2 | 1, 3 | 0, 4, 5 | 1, 2 | 0, 3 | 1, 4, 5 |

| cycle | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| messages | 0, 2 | 1, 3 | 0, 4, 5 | 1, 2 | 0, 3 | 1, 4, 5 | 0, 2 | 1, 3 | 0, 4, 5 | 1, 2 |

The real case is a bit more complex than this:

```
{
    "5": [
        133,
        254,
        340,
        341,
        344,
        346
    ],
    "10": [
        300
    ],
    "20": [
        114,
        115,
        130,
        131,
        132,
        137,
        145,
        162,
        166,
        171,
        203,
        205,
        244,
        245,
        252,
        257,
        262,
        263,
        264,
        265,
        270,
        271,
        272,
        276,
        315,
        316,
        321,
        325,
        330,
        332,
        334,
        335,
        336,
        345
    ],
    "60": [
        175,
        176,
        253,
        255,
        256,
        337,
        342,
        343
    ],
    "100": [
        146,
        155,
        156,
        157,
        206,
        213,
        273,
        274,
        275,
        33,
        34,
        350,
        351,
        352,
        353,
        354,
        355,
        46,
        47,
        66
    ]
}
```

This could be solved by just brute forcing every combination possible, but that would obviously take a long time.
I already tried to search for an algorithm that solves a similar problem but no matter what search terms I use I haven't found a problem that I can use as a guide.
I already tried to apply things like `constrained satisfaction` on it but it's not really fitting that case I think.

Comment: I posted an answer below that will handle the general problem, but if you could change the period 100 to 120, then every pair of periods would satisfy a divisibility relation, and there would be a simple algorithm that doesn't involve integer programming.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thanks a lot for your quick answer. The result looks very good. I haven't herad of integer programming, that's a new concept for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s possible to formulate instances of this problem as a packing
problem and solve them via integer programming. I used OR-Tools. The
minimum number of messages per instant for the instance you give is 4.

```
import math
import pprint

from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp


def distribute(period_to_messages):
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver("SCIP")
    # Maps each message ID to a list of Boolean variables indicating which phase
    # it will have.
    message_to_indicators = {
        message: [solver.BoolVar("") for phase in range(period)]
        for (period, messages) in period_to_messages.items()
        for message in messages
    }
    # Enforces the one-hot constraint for each message's indicator variables.
    for indicators in message_to_indicators.values():
        solver.Add(sum(indicators) == 1)
    # Minimizes the maximum coincidence.
    objective = solver.IntVar(0, solver.infinity(), "")
    solver.Minimize(objective)
    # Standard trick for expressing a maximum to be minimized.
    for t in range(math.lcm(*period_to_messages.keys())):
        # The right-hand side is the coincidence at time t.
        solver.Add(
            objective
            >= sum(
                indicators[t % len(indicators)]
                for indicators in message_to_indicators.values()
            )
        )
    solver.Solve()
    print(objective.solution_value())
    # Decodes the solution.
    return {
        message: phase
        for (message, indicators) in message_to_indicators.items()
        for (phase, indicator) in enumerate(indicators)
        if indicator.solution_value()
    }


pprint.pprint(
    distribute(
        {
            5: [133, 254, 340, 341, 344, 346],
            10: [300],
            20: [
                114,
                115,
                130,
                131,
                132,
                137,
                145,
                162,
                166,
                171,
                203,
                205,
                244,
                245,
                252,
                257,
                262,
                263,
                264,
                265,
                270,
                271,
                272,
                276,
                315,
                316,
                321,
                325,
                330,
                332,
                334,
                335,
                336,
                345,
            ],
            60: [175, 176, 253, 255, 256, 337, 342, 343],
            100: [
                146,
                155,
                156,
                157,
                206,
                213,
                273,
                274,
                275,
                33,
                34,
                350,
                351,
                352,
                353,
                354,
                355,
                46,
                47,
                66,
            ],
        }
    )
)
```

Results:

```
4.0
{33: 96,
 34: 89,
 46: 89,
 47: 69,
 66: 86,
 114: 3,
 115: 11,
 130: 19,
 131: 19,
 132: 5,
 133: 1,
 137: 17,
 145: 2,
 146: 74,
 155: 29,
 156: 74,
 157: 49,
 162: 5,
 166: 10,
 171: 2,
 175: 35,
 176: 32,
 203: 18,
 205: 19,
 206: 86,
 213: 8,
 244: 4,
 245: 16,
 252: 4,
 253: 32,
 254: 3,
 255: 35,
 256: 29,
 257: 13,
 262: 3,
 263: 17,
 264: 11,
 265: 19,
 270: 4,
 271: 0,
 272: 2,
 273: 28,
 274: 14,
 275: 56,
 276: 18,
 300: 7,
 315: 7,
 316: 13,
 321: 0,
 325: 10,
 330: 7,
 332: 4,
 334: 10,
 335: 0,
 336: 8,
 337: 29,
 340: 0,
 341: 3,
 342: 32,
 343: 35,
 344: 2,
 345: 5,
 346: 1,
 350: 16,
 351: 66,
 352: 34,
 353: 21,
 354: 88,
 355: 29}
```

Comment: May I ask you to put some comments into the code to make it easier to follow along on what each step is doing?

Comment: @zero695 Added some comments.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, integer programming–free approach based on number theory.
Works on instances where the Hasse diagram of the periods is a tree
(this is asserted in the code, and satisfied for the given instance).
For a single period, the idea is to distribute phases in a round-robin
manner. To handle multiple periods that are totally ordered by
divisibility, we use a sort of buddy allocation system, dealing a phase
for the smaller period p and then breaking it apart into q/p different
phases for the larger period q.

```
import collections
import math
import pprint


def closure_under_gcd(periods):
    closure = set()
    periods = list(periods)
    while periods:
        p = periods.pop()
        if p in closure:
            continue
        periods.extend(math.gcd(p, q) for q in closure)
        closure.add(p)
    return closure


def divides(p, q):
    return q % p == 0


def is_totally_ordered_by_divisibility(periods):
    periods = sorted(periods)
    return all(divides(periods[j - 1], periods[j]) for j in range(1, len(periods)))


class RootDeck:
    def deal(self):
        return 0

    def period(self):
        return 1


class ChildDeck:
    def __init__(self, parent, period):
        self._parent = parent
        self._period = period
        self._phase = self._period // self._parent.period() - 1

    def deal(self):
        self._phase += 1
        if self._phase == self._period // self._parent.period():
            self._parent_phase = self._parent.deal()
            self._phase = 0
        return self._parent_phase + self._phase * self._parent.period()

    def period(self):
        return self._period


def compute_objective(period_to_messages, message_to_phase):
    time_to_messages = [[] for j in range(math.lcm(*period_to_messages.keys()))]
    for period, messages in period_to_messages.items():
        for message in messages:
            for t in range(message_to_phase[message], len(time_to_messages), period):
                time_to_messages[t].append(message)
    return max(map(len, time_to_messages))


def distribute(period_to_messages):
    periods = closure_under_gcd(period_to_messages.keys())
    assert all(
        is_totally_ordered_by_divisibility(math.gcd(p, q) for p in periods if p < q)
        for q in periods
    )
    phase_decks = {1: RootDeck()}
    message_to_phase = {}
    for q in sorted(periods):
        p = max(p for p in phase_decks.keys() if divides(p, q))
        phase_deck = ChildDeck(phase_decks[p], q)
        if q in period_to_messages:
            for message in sorted(period_to_messages[q]):
                message_to_phase[message] = phase_deck.deal()
        phase_decks[q] = phase_deck
    print(compute_objective(period_to_messages, message_to_phase))
    return message_to_phase


pprint.pprint(
    distribute(
        {
            5: [133, 254, 340, 341, 344, 346],
            10: [300],
            20: [
                114,
                115,
                130,
                131,
                132,
                137,
                145,
                162,
                166,
                171,
                203,
                205,
                244,
                245,
                252,
                257,
                262,
                263,
                264,
                265,
                270,
                271,
                272,
                276,
                315,
                316,
                321,
                325,
                330,
                332,
                334,
                335,
                336,
                345,
            ],
            60: [175, 176, 253, 255, 256, 337, 342, 343],
            100: [
                146,
                155,
                156,
                157,
                206,
                213,
                273,
                274,
                275,
                33,
                34,
                350,
                351,
                352,
                353,
                354,
                355,
                46,
                47,
                66,
            ],
        }
    )
)
```

Results:

```
4
{33: 15,
 34: 35,
 46: 55,
 47: 75,
 66: 95,
 114: 6,
 115: 16,
 130: 2,
 131: 12,
 132: 7,
 133: 0,
 137: 17,
 145: 3,
 146: 1,
 155: 21,
 156: 41,
 157: 61,
 162: 13,
 166: 8,
 171: 18,
 175: 0,
 176: 20,
 203: 4,
 205: 14,
 206: 81,
 213: 11,
 244: 9,
 245: 19,
 252: 0,
 253: 40,
 254: 1,
 255: 10,
 256: 30,
 257: 10,
 262: 5,
 263: 15,
 264: 1,
 265: 11,
 270: 6,
 271: 16,
 272: 2,
 273: 31,
 274: 51,
 275: 71,
 276: 12,
 300: 1,
 315: 7,
 316: 17,
 321: 3,
 325: 13,
 330: 8,
 332: 18,
 334: 4,
 335: 14,
 336: 9,
 337: 50,
 340: 2,
 341: 3,
 342: 5,
 343: 25,
 344: 4,
 345: 19,
 346: 0,
 350: 91,
 351: 6,
 352: 26,
 353: 46,
 354: 66,
 355: 86}
```

Comment: Also a very interesting approach. Could you explain a little bit more what requirements have to be met to satisfy `is_totally_ordered_by_divisibility`?

Comment: @zero695 It’s easier to give examples of what isn’t allowed. Given
distinct primes p, q, and r and messages with period pq, pr, and qr,
then that’s not allowed. Given distinct primes p and q and messages with
period p, q, and pq, then that’s not allowed. This is because these
periods cause partial synchronization with other messages in two
different ways.

The instance in the question is OK because 5 divides 10 divides 20
divides both 60 and 100, and the gcd of 60 and 100 is 20. The period-60
and period-100 messages will sync up if and only if they have the same
phase mod 20.

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately this won't be the only message/period combination, I only used this one as an example. So I guess I will use the first solution.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that, if partial synchronisation is not a problem (i.e. I don't need a perfect solution), I can remove the assert? Then it's only required to sort the periods, right?

Comment: @zero695 Keep the closure, but yes, you can drop the assert for a heuristic.

Comment: @zero695 The theory is an extended consequence of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem . If the periods were pairwise relatively prime, then it wouldn't matter what the phases were. If the periods were totally ordered by divisibility, and let's say powers of 2 specifically, then if you apply the bit reversal permutation, then we really are just doing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation . The theoretical complexity arises from trying to combine these insights into a single algorithm.

Comment: Okay then I will drop the assert and use the algorithm in an heuristical manner.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will take a look at it.